# Android WebView is taking more time to load website then the browser in laptop, both laptop and android mobile are using same internet connection

Tags: android, performance, webview, desktop

Is there something I am missing to set some property of webview?
I have set following property but no improvement in performance:

```
        webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        // Enable the caching for web view
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        // Specify the app cache path
        webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getCacheDir().getPath());
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        else {
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: `more time to load website then the browser in laptop`,  Wrong comparison. You should compare with a browser on your Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using `webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);` which disallows any kind of caching in your Android WebView.

While browsing in browser, most of your content is loaded from cache, which results in difference of loading time. Hence, affects overall performance.

You should use it as follows to improve caching:

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: I have tried with LOAD_DEFAULT, LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK as well but no improvement.Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Press Ctrl + F5 on your browser, then compare both of them, it is browser's cache, which allows faster loading of website.